# iptables logging packets coming from the outside world

Tags: networking, security, iptables, logging, tcpdump

I want to log all INPUT packets that do not originate in the LAN for audit purposes, I have a script with tcpdump basically appending to a file the result from this:

```
tcpdump "(dst net 192.168.0.0/24 and ! src net 192.168.0.0/24)"
```

however, I've seen some outside attempts in /var/log/syslog

```
[567325.985994] iptables INPUT denied: IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=..... SRC=69.163.149.200 DST=192.168.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=50281 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51380 DPT=1194 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[567895.076532] iptables INPUT denied: IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=.... SRC=72.21.91.19 DST=192.168.0.2 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=52589 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

which don't show up in tcpdump outout. I want to add a rule like

```
-A INPUT -j LOG
```

but I would like (if it makes sense) to avoid putting in the log input packets from the LAN

is it enough to put this?

```
-A INPUT ! -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j LOG
```

BTW, as an a side question, does iptables support logging different things to different files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iptables always logs to syslog's kernel facility, you can separate your [syslog facilities into different files](http://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/x4238.html) - see the [syslog.conf documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf) for details.

Your rule

> -A INPUT ! -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j LOG

would log packets which do not have the source IP 192.168.0.0/24, but the iptables logging only covers some of the packet header data, not the packet's payload.

> so, how can I capture the payload?

tcpdump is the tool that would capture payload. You should either specify the interface you expect the traffic to come in at explicitly (-i eth1) or use any interface (-i any). You might also want to increase the snaplen (-s parameter) and write the capture to a file in binary format (-W parameter).

But due to the fact that tcpdump is not a security tool but a diagnosis tool with a difficult security history and probably runs with root priveleges in your config (although there are [ways to run it non-root](http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/mar/19/sniffing-wireshark-non-root-user/)), you should consider a different solution written with security in mind - [IDS systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) might be suitable.

Comment: so, how can i capture the payload? i presume tcpdump should be doing it, but it doesn't output anything

Comment: Answer edited to incorporate your question and some comments

Comment: cool, i assumed tcpdump captured any by default